# Google sheet - A script attached to this document needs your permission to run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet I created a spread sheet on google for small bookkeeping 3-4 years ago, that I have not used for a year or so. Now, the system cannot send emails anymore.

I created this using the same google account that I have now.
My google account is registered as a developer.

I get this message:

```
Google hasn’t verified this app

The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account. 
Until the developer (myaccount@gmail.com) verifies this app with Google, you shouldn't use it.
```

This has worked and I recall giving access to such data; but now I cannot find it.
It is sending emails, which would be from my account.
Now it is like I need to allow myself the access?

How and where do I do that?

I see that I gave some access to the system on February 11, 2021

Here I can see that I have granted access to myself to send emails and anything on spread sheets.

Comment: Can you confirm if this application is created through Google Apps Script or has this been deployed as a web application?

Comment: @CenturyTuna it is just a sheet

Answer (score 0):

I removed my rights and applied them again, then it worked.